# How stop SKAction background music

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm trying to make a game and in the main menu, there is a label to start music, and another to stop music.

```
let backgroundMusic = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("background.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)

 override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchedNode = atPoint(location)
            if touchedNode.name == self.BEGIN_MUSIC {
                // start music
                self.run(backgroundMusic)
            }
            if touchedNode.name == self.STOP_MUSIC {
                // stop music
                SKAction.stop()
            }
        }
    }
```

the music starts fine and works on all scenes which is what i wanted. But when I press the stop music, the music keeps playing. How do I stop the music.

I've tried SKAction.pause(), i've tried using withKey: "music" and then self.removeAction(forKey: "music").

I also tried making backgroundMusic: SKAudioNode and this worked but once i stopped the music i couldn't turn it back on, also it doesn't work on any other scene just the main menu.

How do I stop the sound?

Comment: You will need to change your approach on how to play music. According to the developer doucmentation, SKAction.playSoundFileNamed should be used for short sounds and AVAudioPlayer for long running background music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue a while ago: This is how I got it working. This is specific for background music.

```
   var backgroundMusic: AVAudioPlayer!


   func playMusic() {
      if let musicURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "musicSource", withExtension: "wav") {
          if let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: musicURL) {
              backgroundMusic = audioPlayer
              backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
              backgroundMusic.play()
              backgroundMusic.volume = 0.2
            
          }    
      }
   }


   override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

      if let touch = touches.first {
          let pos = touch.location(in: self)
          let node = self.atPoint(pos)

       let musicOff = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "musicOff")

       if node == musicButton && musicOff == false {

               backgroundMusic.stop()
               UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "musicOff")

       }

       if node == musicButton && musicOff == true {

                backgroundMusic.play()
                backgroundMusic.volume = 0.3
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "musicOff")

       }
     }
   }
```